# Proving whether $p_{2n-1} = \frac 1 {2n-1}$ and $p_{2n} = 1 + \frac 1 {2n}$ converges to $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

> For each positive integer $n$, let $p_{2n-1} = \frac 1 {2n-1}$ and let $p_{2n} = 1 + \frac 1 {2n}$. Does the sequence $p_1,p_2,p_3,\dots$ converge to $0$?

I have to prove this formally.

So far I know that the sequence $(p_n)$ does not converge to $x$ if there exists an open interval $(a,b)$ containing $x$ such that for every natural number $N$ there exists a natural number $n, n > N$ such that $p_n$ is not an element of $(a,b)$.

I do not really know how to prove or disprove this converges to $0$ though.

Comment: Do you know about subsequences? These are two ($p_{2n}$ and $p_{2n-1}$) that converge to difference limits so $p_n$ cannot converge.

Comment: Alternative hint: $\;p_n - p_{n-1} \to 1\,$, so the sequence is not a [Cauchy sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence), thus not convergent.

Comment: In keeping with the comment by @AloneAndConfused I wonder whether the original problem was simply to show that $\{p_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge at all (hence *a fortiori* does not converge to the specific value of zero)...

Comment: No `\dfrac` in titles please. The standard command for fractions is `\frac`.

Answer (score 1):

Your sequence does not converge to $0$.

Let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$.

Hence, easy to see that for all $N>0$ $a_{2[N]+4}\geq\epsilon$,

which is contradiction with the definition of convergible to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=-0.5$ and $b=0.5$. $(a,b)$ contains $0$.

Given any $N \in \mathbb{N}$, we let $n=2N$, hence $n > N$, $p_n=1+\frac{1}{n} > 1 > 0.5$.

hence $p_n$ is not an element of $(a,b)$.